# Convert PHP compatible Regular Expression to MySql compatible regular expression - To extract Australian Mobile Numbers

Tags: mysql, regex, posix, pcre

I have a Regular expression which is running very well in PHP code. It throws errors when I am using it with MYSQL query.

```py
^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})61(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[4]\d{8}$
```

Please help me to convert it into MYSQL compatible regular expression.

Comment: What MySQL version? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I have tried below query in phpmyadmin
>> SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE `Mobile_Phone` REGEXP "^(?:(?:\+|0{​0,2}​)61(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[4]\d{​8}​$" ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 0, 25

It is throwing error like
#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'regexp'
@WiktorStribiżew please help to convert. Thank you!

Comment: Try `^(([+]|0{0,2})61([[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]*)?|0?)?4[0-9]{8}$`

Comment: That's Perfect!! Thank you for Amazing & quick support. :). Please add in solution so I can accept it.

Comment: Sure, just give me a minute or two.

Comment: Sure let me check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query to extract Australian Mobile Numbers (starts with 4, +61, 61, 04, etc.) in MySQL

```sql
^(([+]|0{0,2})61([[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]*)?|0?)?4[0-9]{8}$
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - start of the first group:

  - `([+]|0{0,2})` - Group 2 matching `+` or zero, one or two zeros
  - `61` - `61` string
  - `([[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]*)?` - an optional Group 3 matching a  hyphen enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `|` - or

  - `0?` - an optional zero
- `)?` - end of the first group, that is optional due to `?`
- `4[0-9]{8}` - `4` and then any eight digits
- `$` - end of string.